# Mysql compare json data with database

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, twitch

The idea behind the code below is to make a "Unfollower alert" for Twitch users/streamers.. The concept: Twitch api gives me a list of current followers of a channel which in my code if i find a new name I put him in the database under follower name and the same for follow time. My problem: I can`t get the sql code to understand and compare the current followers with the database and display the follower which is missing from the api but not in the database.

```
 <?php
 $connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","twitchun");
 $channelsApi = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows? 
 to_id=176714165&first=10';
 $channelName = '';
 $clientId = 'pm7oxir9hxzhrl0hnzdxdrg';
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
   'Client-ID: ' . $clientId
 ),
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_URL => $channelsApi . $channelName
 ));
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 //echo $response;
 $json = json_decode($response, true);
 foreach ($json['data'] as $names){

  echo '<p>'.$names['from_name'].'</p>';
}



 foreach ($json['data'] as $names){
 $result = $connection->query("SELECT follower_name FROM followers WHERE 
 follower_name = '".$names['from_name']."'");
 if($result->num_rows == 0) {
 //if follower doesnt exist in database put him in
  mysqli_query($connection, 'INSERT into followers(follower_name, 
  follow_time) VALUES ("'.$names['from_name'].'", 
 "'.$names['followed_at'].'")'); 
 } else {
 //if follower exists in database and in json
 }
```

part where it doesnt work

```
 $fnames= $names['from_name'];
 $result2 = $connection->query("SELECT follower_name FROM followers WHERE 
 follower_name <> '".$fnames."' order by follow_time desc");

   $unfollow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
   foreach($unfollow as $unfollower){
       echo '<p style="color:red">'.$unfollower.'</p>';
   }

 }
```

Comment: At what step in your logic is it not working correctly?

Comment: I edited it sorry

Comment: So in the part that does not work.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I get all followers from a channel, I put them in the DB under follower_name. If someone stops following (Is in the database, but not in the API or JSON), I want to echo his name.. In this case a name : BaychevLive should appear, instead the first name appears as much times as there are names

Comment: I hope that isn't your actual client id in the code...

Comment: So to clarify.  You basically just want to test to see if BaychevLive is on the DB?  If he is on the DB you want to display his name.  Is that correct?

Comment: "Select follower_name from... where follower_name DOES NOT EXIST in the $fnames"
$fnames = names from the json

Comment: Your logic here is messed up.  Your else statement basically guarantees that the name is already on the DB,  The query that you have there now will select all of the names on the DB except the one that you are testing.  I am sorry, I am still confused.  The `$fnames` WILL ALWAYS EXIST on the DB.